# Convert string duration column to time in hours & minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame which contain two columns: time column `df["Start_Time"]` in the format of `%H:%M:%S` & a duration column `df["Duration"]` which shows the duration that was spent doing a specific activity.
This is a sample of the data:

```
    Start_Time  Duration
0   07:30:00    03:00
1   07:30:00    06:00
2   07:30:00    07:00
3   07:30:00    28:00
4   08:50:00    50:00
5   11:30:00    32:00
6   10:30:00    24:00
7   06:45:00    15:55
```

My end goal is to sum the `duration` to the `start time`, figure out the end_time & how many days we passed doing this activity.
The problem is I don't know how to convert the column Duration into time column. Duration is a string column. I know I can't use `pd.to_datetime()`.
I tried using `strftime` but I had errors. Any ideas on how to convert the column duration ?

Comment: Does any of the answers answer your question? Please mark as is :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime(format=...)` and `pd.to_timedelta()` to do this. In your example you can do the following. We first need to add `'00:'` add the beginning of your column `Duration` as this will represent the hours (now it can be used in `pd.to_timedelta()`).

```
df['delta'] = '00:' + df['Duration']
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Start_Time, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df['delta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.delta)
```

Now you can add columns `start` and `delta` and convert it to time:

```
df['sum'] = (df['start'] + df['delta']).dt.time
df = df.drop(columns=['start', 'delta'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Start_Time Duration       sum
0   07:30:00    03:00  07:33:00
1   07:30:00    06:00  07:36:00
2   07:30:00    07:00  07:37:00
3   07:30:00    28:00  07:58:00
4   08:50:00    50:00  09:40:00
5   11:30:00    32:00  12:02:00
6   10:30:00    24:00  10:54:00
7   06:45:00    15:55  07:00:55
```

Answer (score 1):

From your dataset, first we convert the column `Start_Time` to [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) :

```py
df['Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Then, we can convert the `Duration` column to seconds :

```py
df['Duration_second'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Duration'], format='%M:%S').dt.minute * 60 + pd.to_datetime(df['Duration'], format='%M:%S').dt.second
```

We compute the addition with [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) :

```py
df['Result'] = df['Start_Time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration_second'], unit='s')
```

To finish, we keep only the `%H:%M:%S` format using the [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html) method to get the expected result :

```py
df['Start_Time'] = df['Start_Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['Result'] = df['Result'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Output

```
>>> df
    Start_Time  Duration    Duration_second Result
0   07:30:00    03:00       180             07:33:00
1   07:30:00    06:00       360             07:36:00
2   07:30:00    07:00       420             07:37:00
3   07:30:00    28:00       1680            07:58:00
4   08:50:00    50:00       3000            09:40:00
5   11:30:00    32:00       1920            12:02:00
6   10:30:00    24:00       1440            10:54:00
7   06:45:00    15:55       955             07:00:55
```

We can drop the `Duration_second` column using [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) :

```py
df = df.drop('Duration_second', axis=1)
```